# using tesseract for android

Tags: android, ocr

want a running example of OCR in android, I have done some research and find an example that implements OCR in android.

https://github.com/rmtheis/tess-two and in it there are three projects files...

eyes-two
tess-two
tess-two-test
I have executed the "tess-two-test" project by importing the three project files but "tess-two-test" does not include any activities so it will not run.

can any one explain me this functionality step by step

Comment: They have step by step tutorials on their site. If you've tried something, post what you've done so we can see what you've tried and help you fix it.

Comment: http://gaut.am/making-an-ocr-android-app-using-tesseract/

Answer (score 2):

You have to have Android SDK and Android NDK running. The NDK will help you to compile the project in a right way. After that you need to have also apache ANT. Here is a link. A little bit old but could help you to know exactly what you have to do and a example project after you get tess-two compiled. http://gaut.am/making-an-ocr-android-app-using-tesseract/